# Showing the post only when there is title, thumbnail and the content in Custom Fields

Tags: custom-field

I am learning so please don't be cruel to me. I need Your help. I am trying to use Custom Fields and the loop is working BUT I have four sections and when the section contains the content is fine there is a title and the content shown but when there is no content there is a title shown only BUT I would like nothing to be shown just empty space with no title. Can You please give me a hand and show the "if" I should make. This is the working code:

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'ogloszenia',
    'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC' ) ); ?>

    <?php while( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">

            <?php
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail();
            }
            ?>

            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        </div><!-- end col -->
    <?php endwhile ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_the_content` to a variable instead, so you can check it is not empty first:

```
<?php $content = get_the_content(); ?>
<?php if (!empty($content)) : ?>
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
    <p><?php echo $content; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `if ( get_the_content() ) :` would be sufficient.

Comment: true but then you would be processing all filters on `the_content` twice, this is more *efficient*.

Comment: The `the_content` filters are not applied to `get_the_content()`.

Comment: wow totally my bad, lol... how strange for the result of `the_content` and `get_the_content` to be so divergent! whooda thunkit.

Comment: Yeah, `get_the_content()` is a very strange function.